# Simple NGinx rewrite is redirecting

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to setup a friendly URL for a website running on my Nginx server but for some reason, the url's are being redirected instead of being rewritten.

For instance If a user visits mydomain.com/aboutme/ I want mydomain.com/aboutme/ to stay in the address bar, but for the content to be pulled from mydomain.com/aboutme.php

In my Nginx site configuration I have the following (a simple example with some stuff chopped out for simplicities sake):

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/aboutus/$ http://www.mydomain.com/aboutus.php permanent;
    }

}
```

For whatever reason, Nginx seems to insist on redirecting the 'friendly' url to the php file, but I want a more traditional "rewrite" (like I've done before in Apache mod_rewrite without issue).

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'll be damned if I can work out what.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite)?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a 301 redirect because [you specifically asked for a 301 redirect](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite).

To fix the problem, use a relative destination URL, and `last` instead of `permanent`.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/aboutus/$ /aboutus.php last;
```